# Writing to Shadow Memory?

Tags: memory, dos

I want to write F000:0000 ~ FFFF:0000 in real mode (DOS).
But this area is write-protected.

I tried to find datasheet of CPU and Northbridge.
But, i can't find write method of shadow ram.

My system configuraion:
M/B: ASUS P5B(965P Chipset)
CPU: Intel Pentium 4 Series

### BIOS: AMI

---

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what you're trying to do, and why you're writing to Shadow Memory?

Comment: Are you going to patch the BIOS?

Comment: futureelite7 : I want to experiment, control BIOS execution real-time.

Comment: Try finding a book on the subject...

Answer (score 0):

F000:0000 ~ FFFF:0000 is a memory range pointing to HMA, on all processors after 80286. You can read more on that [here](http://download.adamas.ai/dlbase/Stuff/VX%20Heavens%20Library/vqm01.html).

To use it without HIMEM.SYS you should do following:

> You can directly control the 8042 keyboard controller. Using command
>   D1. Write Output Port: next byte written to port 60h is placed in the
>   8042 output port.

```
.286
                 mov     al,0d1h         ;send command to 8042
                 out     64h,al
 reloop:         in      al,64h          ;check that port 60h is available
                 or      al,02h
                 jnz     reloop
                 mov     al,11100011b    ;keep keyboard working and gate a20
                 out     60h,al
                 push    -1              ;set es=ffffh
                 pop     es
                 push    00h
                 pop     ds              ;set ds=0000h
                 mov     di,10h          ;check if it worked, compare
                 xor     si,si           ;ffff:0010h to 0000:0000 for 16 bytes
                 mov     cx,di           ;set cx to 10h
                 cld
                 rep     cmpsb           ;compare it
                 je      failed
                [...]                    ;worked, copy virus to ffff:xxxx
 failed:         jmp     short failed    ;do whatever
```